# Entity Framework: Using Multiple Custom History Context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the code that map the __MigrationHistory to the existing database table.

```
namespace Alvin_CMS.Migrations
{
    public class CustomHistoryContext : HistoryContext
    {
        public CustomHistoryContext(DbConnection dbConnection, string defaultSchema)
        : base(dbConnection, defaultSchema)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().ToTable(tableName: "__MigrationHistory", schemaName: "dbo");
            //modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().Property(p => p.MigrationId).HasColumnName("Migration_ID");
        }
    }

    public class CustomHistoryConfiguration : DbConfiguration
    {
        public CustomHistoryConfiguration()
        {
            this.SetHistoryContext("System.Data.SqlClient",
            (connection, defaultSchema) => new CustomHistoryContext(connection, "dbo"));
        }
    }
}
```

Also I have another custom history context:

```
namespace EAccounting.Migrations
{
    public class CustomHistoryContext : HistoryContext
    {
        public CustomHistoryContext(DbConnection dbConnection, string defaultSchema)
            : base(dbConnection, defaultSchema)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().ToTable(tableName: "__MigrationHistory", schemaName: "EAccounting");
            //modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().Property(p => p.MigrationId).HasColumnName("Migration_ID");
        }
    }

    public class CustomHistoryConfiguration : DbConfiguration
    {
        public CustomHistoryConfiguration()
        {
            this.SetHistoryContext("System.Data.SqlClient",
            (connection, defaultSchema) => new CustomHistoryContext(connection, "EAccounting"));
        }
    }
}
```

And I call this in my code:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<EAccounting.Models.EAccountingMigrationDBContext, EAccounting.Migrations.Configuration>());
```

I have multiple databases which have their own custom migration history context. How can I let the database initializer for the migration history to choose which history context they will use?

Answer (score 1):

I have a system with two different DbContext subclasses in two different assemblies, and these two contexts use two different HistoryContexts. The trick for me was to use two different HistoryContext *tables*, and to ensure that the DbMigrationsConfiguration subclass for each DbContext subclass includes code that registers the right HistoryContext subclass when the database initializes.

base db migration class:

```
   public class DbMigrationsConfigurationBase<TContext> : DbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext>, IDbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext> where TContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public DbMigrationsConfigurationBase(Func<DbConnection, string, HistoryContext> historyContextFactory)
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        MigrationsDirectory = @"Migrations";
        RegisterHistoryContextFactory(historyContextFactory);
    }

    private void RegisterHistoryContextFactory(Func<DbConnection, string, HistoryContext> historyContextFactory)
    {
        foreach (ConnectionStringSettings connectionString in ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString.ProviderName))
            {
                SetHistoryContextFactory(connectionString.ProviderName, historyContextFactory);
            }
        }
    }

    public IDbMigrator GetMigrator()
    {
        return new DbMigratorWrapper(new DbMigrator(this));
    }
}
```

Example context-specific migration config class:

```
    public sealed class MySpecialDatabaseMigrationConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfigurationBase<MySpecialDatabase>
{
    private static readonly Func<DbConnection, string, HistoryContext> HistoryContextFactory =
        (connection, schema) => new MySpecialDatabaseHistoryContext(connection, schema);
    public MySpecialDatabaseMigrationConfiguration(): base(HistoryContextFactory)
    {
        ContextKey = "MyNamespace.MySpecialDatabase";
    }
}
```

Then in my database initializer I ensure the migration config is instantiated at initialization time...

```
    public class CreateOrMigrateDatabaseInitializer<TContext, TConfiguration> : IDatabaseInitializer<TContext>
    where TContext : DbContext, IDbContext
    where TConfiguration : IDbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext>, new()
{
    private readonly string _connection;

    public CreateOrMigrateDatabaseInitializer(string connection, ILogger logger = null)
    {
        Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(connection), "connection");
        _connection = connection;
    }

    public void InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
    {
        Contract.Requires(context != null, "context");

        IDbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext> configuration = new TConfiguration()
        {
            TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(_connection)
        };

        if (!context.Database.Exists() || !context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(throwIfNoMetadata: false))
        {
            var migrator = configuration.GetMigrator();

            foreach (string s in migrator.GetPendingMigrations())
            {
                migrator.Update(s);
            }
        }

        Seed(context);

        context.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am running  6.2.0 with code first.
I just use a different schema for each DbContext

Inside the DbContext I set the default schema

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("schema1");
    }
```

this causes a separate __MigrationHistory  table for each DbContext

Answer (score 0):

You have to add attribute above the context, juts like this:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(CustomeConfiguration))]
```

Then try to register the configuration before initialize the context in global asax or in the app config.

```
DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new TDBConfigurations());
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/code-based